# Using ports to plot in elm

Tags: plot, elm, dygraphs

I need to do some significant plotting for my application and I am not sure if I am going to be able to get `elm-plot` to do everything I need.  As such, I thought I would fall back to something that I have used before - mainly [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/).  I believe that the function `new Dygraph(..)` returns an html canvas element.  Does anyone have an example as to how to insert this into an elm application or any suggestions as to how to go about this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to see if you can find an option to attach the dygraph to a div that you *create in Elm*. After that - and as long as dygraph is not going to start mutating any other part of the DOM - you should be OK.

Looking at https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs-es6/blob/master/index.html it seems that you can indeed pass a dom id to dygraph.